# WPF DataGrid binding doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here's my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MoonMining" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MarketData.MoonMinerals, ElementName=window}">
    <DataGrid.DataContext>
        <local:MoonMineral/>
    </DataGrid.DataContext>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        .. Yes i have columns and they are irrelevant to my question .
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

`MarketData` is a class which contains most of my programs logic. `MoonMinerals` is defined in that class:

```
public class MarketData
{
   private ObservableCollection<MoonMineral> _moonMinerals = new ObservableCollection<MoonMineral>();

   public ObservableCollection<MoonMineral> MoonMinerals
   {
       get { return _moonMinerals; }
       set { _moonMinerals = value; }
   }
 }
```

And here's my `MoonMineral` class:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class MoonMineral
{
    public MoonMineral()
        : this("Def", "Def")
    {
    }

    public MoonMineral(string name, string rarity)
    {
        Name = name;
        Rarity = rarity;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public string Rarity { get; set; }
    public double TransportVolume { get; set; }
    public double TransportCosts { get; set; }
    public double GrossProfit { get; set; }
    public double NetProfit { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using PostSharp to clear up my code, but when I manually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` I have the same problem.

Now the problem is that my `DataGrid` doesn't update by itself, I have to manually call this in a method which modifies `MoonMinerals`:

```
var bindingExpression = MoonMining.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
if (bindingExpression != null)
    bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();
```

I know this isn't big of a deal, but I wanted to finally manage to bind data to ui entirely using xaml. All my previous attempts involved setting `DataGrids` `ItemsSource` property every time I updated the data.

Comment: Do you change `MoonMinerals` property and if yes will it raise `PropertyChanged` event like properties of `MoonMineral`?

Comment: i don't understand where MarketData is .. 
could you show the class . 
and why is your item source binding to ElementName=window

Comment: @dkozl I'm using PostSharp to do that for me, but yes, I've tried raising it manually also and it did not work.

Comment: I can see you do it for `MoonMineral` class but do you do it for class which exposes `ObservableCollection<MoonMineral> MoonMinerals` property, which in your case seems to be some `window`?

Comment: MoonMineral isn't a static class right ?

Comment: Where do you set MarketData as DataContext of the DataGrid? What is the DataContext of your View? Why do you define `<local:MoonMineral/>` as DataContext of the DataGrid in XAML?

Comment: @dkozl do you know how i can undo an edit on this question ? 
i put so much irrelevant things i excedantly removed the columns he wanted to update

Comment: @dkozl I actually haven't thought about that. window is my MainWindow form, I just implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my MainWindow and that seems to have worked, thanks! You can put your comment in an answer and I'll choose it as best. By the way, if anyone has any tips on how to implement it better then feel free to help, it's my first bigger app I'm working on.

Comment: @eranotzap you can rollback to [revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25612243/revisions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up comments you're implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for `MoonMineral` class and use `ObservableCollection` which will handle changes to the collection but there seems to be nothing in place to handle changes to `MoonMinerals` property

```
private ObservableCollection<MoonMineral> _moonMinerals = new ObservableCollection<MoonMineral>();

public ObservableCollection<MoonMineral> MoonMinerals
{
    get { return _moonMinerals; }
    set { _moonMinerals = value; }
}
```

You can either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the class that exposes `MoonMinerals` property or change it to read-only and use only one instance of `_moonMinerals` and simply clear it and add/remove items

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<MoonMineral> _moonMinerals = new ObservableCollection<MoonMineral>();

public ObservableCollection<MoonMineral> MoonMinerals
{
    get { return _moonMinerals; }
}
```

Also, as a side note, you don't need

```
<DataGrid.DataContext>
    <local:MoonMineral/>
</DataGrid.DataContext>
```

as this will set `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` to new instance of `MoonMineral`. It works in your case as you change binding context of `ItemsSource` using `ElementName` so `DataContext` is not used in your case.

Comment: Thanks, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class that exposes `MoonMinerals` worked.
About that side note though, I might still need it, I get a notification "cannot resolve symbol" when I bind a `Setter`s value on one of the columns if `DataContext` is not set. The `Setter` still works even with that notification so I'm not sure what's up.